# Spring MVC: cant redirect on html-page: 404-error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, controller, http-status-code-404

I created a simple @Controller for redirection:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ( "/" )
public class HtmlTestingController {

@GetMapping
public String showPage() {
    return "redirect:access_denied";
   }
 }
```

Descriptor is:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring/spring-app.xml
        classpath:spring/spring-db.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

mvc-configuration in spring-mvc.xml is:

```
 <bean class="ru.spb.dreamwhite.web.json.JacksonObjectMapper" id="objectMapper" factory-method="getMapper"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">

    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>

</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="conversionService">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="WEB-INF/denied/"
      p:suffix=".html"
      />

<context:component-scan base-package="ru.spb.**.web"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

webapp structure is in attachment:

[image: webapp]

When I run tomcat it redirects me on url:  http://localhost:8080/test/access_denied.

But with 404-error.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: Most people I know don't use XML configuration anymore, unless it is a legacy project. Do check out Spring's `JavaConfig` once.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `redirect:/denied/access_denied`?

Comment: redirect:/denied/access_denied   does not help. Result is the same: 404

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/denied/"
      p:suffix=".html"/>

 <mvc:resources mapping="/denied/**" location="/WEB-INF/denied/"/>
```

And controller:

```
@GetMapping
public String showPage() {
    return "forward:/denied/access_denied.html";
}
```